# Extremely slow with C++ LSP and fairly big project

Tags: neovim, lazyvim

How do i troubleshoot what is causing below problem.

### Problem:

neovim unresponsive for several seconds (10-30 seconds) for any keys

### Setup:

Neovim 0.9.2 and neovim nightly

- workspace with > 900 files
- C++ files
- Clangd with Neovim NativeLSP using LazyVim

### My triage so far

- Disabled LSP (using LspStop)
- no issue with non C++ file
- No issues with smaller projects (<50 files)

Comment: Try to do profiling while saving files. It is a common issue unfortentently. `:help profile`

Comment: Try [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) as a tip to identify the cause of slowness

Comment: It is difficult to help you without being able to reproduce the problem. I'm using [Coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) with coc-clangd on a very large projects (over 6500 files) and it works fine. I suspect that you have multiple plugin that are conflicting each other. Are you using a distribution [LazyVim](https://www.lazyvim.org/) or simply the [Lazy](https://www.lazyvim.org/) plugin manager?

Comment: If you are using LazyVim did you use the [CLangd](https://www.lazyvim.org/extras/lang/clangd) page to add support for Cpp? Did you try to uninstall some of the parts (e.g. nvim-treesitter, clangd_extensions, nvim-dap, nvim-lspconfig)? which one is creating the problem?